# Cross-Origin Request Blocked error in Amazon Web Services

Tags: amazon-web-services, cors

The short version of my problem is: I am using Amazon Web Services to host a static website and a servlet, I would like to have JavaScript code in the static website send GET requests to the servlet, but I'm getting "Cross-Origin Request Blocked" errors.  Here's the long version:

I have created and deployed a servlet on Amazon's Elastic Beanstalk.  The servlet takes in GET requests, does some processing, and spits out a JSON.  I registered a domain using Route53 (let's call it "example.com") and used Route53 to create an alias for the servlet; let's call it "app.example.com".

I am also hosting a static webpage using a combination of S3 and Route 53.  I am able to send GET requests to the servlet and get responses via an HTML document in my domain's S3 bucket.  What I want to do is include a little JavaScript code in the HTML document which makes a GET request by calling "app.example.com/keyword=somestring" and which parses the JSON spat out by the servlet as a response.  I have tested the JavaScript code with a sample JSON output stored on my local machine and it works fine.

The problem is when I try to have the script get the JSON via a GET request I get a "Cross-Origin Request Blocked" error in my console.  I went to my application's bucket in S3 and added the following CORS rule:

```
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
```

but the problem persists.  What can I do?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, your HTML files are hosted on your S3 bucket. And you will like to use these (static?) pages to send `GET` requests to your servlet on Elastic Beanstalk?

Comment: @isim I have two separate S3 buckets: one containing an index.html file with all my JavaScript code, and another containing the .war file with my servlet code (generated when I uploaded my servlet to my Elastic Beanstalk application).  The bucket containing index.html, a static page with javascript code, is called (for the sake of this example) "example.com" and the bucket containing my Elastic Beanstalk app was named by Amazon when I created my Elastic Beanstalk application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got this all backwards. The S3 CORS rules are used if you are trying to connect **to the S3 hosted static website** from another domain.

In your case, you're actually trying to connect **from the S3 hosted static website** to another domain, so the CORS headers need to be sent out by the app running on that domain (by your Elastic Beanstalk application).

Comment: You are correct: I want to connect from the S3 hosted static website to my Elastic Beanstalk application.  I have added the CORS rule in my question to both my "example.com" bucket and my Elastic Beanstalk app bucket.  Are you saying that I need to add some code to my servlet (hosted by Elastic Beanstalk) which includes CORS headers?  If so, can you explain (or give references) how to do this?

Comment: You might want to have a look at http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter & http://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/customize-elastic-beanstalk-using-configuration-files/

Comment: Having read both links, I think I need to add some CORS headers to my servlet response.  I'm still confused about how to do this, but it's late so I will look at this again after getting some sleep.  Your remarks so far have been very helpful, and if you have any further suggestions I'm sure I will appreciate them.